# SharePoint 2010 site collection template not visible

Tags: 2010, site-template

I have a document center of which i would like to create a template for re use. I have used [Todd's guide](http://toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=218) to do this and it's all working fine. Except when I try to include the site content in the template, it's not visible in the list of custom templates.

-> I can use a template that does not have content included.
-> I added the wsp files to the solution gallery. 
-> I Activated the solutions.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** The problem is that the template is not visible in the template selection. When you look at this  [Image](http://toddklindt.com/blog/Blog%20pictures/080310_2041_CreatingaSi11.png) there is no custom template available, i did however added it to the library

Answer (score 1):

In looking at Tony's blog post, did you check the "Include Content" checkbox when saving the template.  It is not mentioned, and he did not do this for his template, but I think it is needed for yours.

[image: Template Settings]

Comment: Yes i did check the include content. The problem is that the template not visible. The template is added tot the library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the size of the content that can be included to a template.

It's possible you have too much data stored. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it chokes when saving the template if the content size is over 10MB (...OOB limit), so I doubt this is the problem.  There is a stsadm command to change that though: stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size -propertyvalue 52428800

Comment: The size of the template i use is 633 kb. So i don't think that this is the case.